# Call modal form from another modal form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have best practice question. 
I‘m developing the list of contracts and use the modal form to register the new contract. This form contains `DropDownList` with ***autocomplete*** function to choose the project manager from Managers list. In case the required manager is not on the list the button `New manager` should open the form to register the new manager and after `submit` continue with the first form . How to do it better from the modal form ?

Comment: Can you please add your code, whatever you have tried so far?

Comment: If this is more about the user experience than about how to code it, you might be better off asking this on the [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site